# Jwplayer subtitles in Chrome appear too big

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, subtitle, closed-captions

I have a page with jwplayer to play videos, but subtitles in chrome appears too big.

You can check it in the next example page: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430278-cea-608-and-708-captions

Firefo example. Captions are ok in size
[image: Firefox is ok]

Chrome example. Captions are too big.
[image: Chrome subtitles are too big]

Comment: can you make sure that your chrome is not zoomed in?

Comment: Hello @chuplu my zoom is set to 100% in both navigators.

Answer (score 0):

It happens probably because Chrome does not apply (overrides) any styling of native track elements (608 subtitles, VTT) and scales them automatically based on player/screen size and OS settings.

It is mentioned here (see Properties section, fontSize property): https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1482067-styling-captions-for-fcc-compliance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the styling of the captions using the captions configuration block. This is primarily relevant in the context of accessibility requirements, such as those mandated by the FCC in the United States.

And here is the embed code associated with this setup:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "/assets/sintel.mp4",
    image: "/assets/sintel.jpg",
    tracks: [{ 
        file: "/assets/captions.vtt"
    }]
}],
captions: {
    color: '#FF0000',
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundOpacity: 50
    }
});`
```

Yes, go to this link for more help!
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1482067-styling-captions-for-fcc-compliance